# Window cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

Why can't I call Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE?

It says Window cannot be resolved to a variable, it does not give me the import option in the pop up dialog.

```
 dialog_shownote = new Dialog(WrittenTest.this, R.style.PauseDialog);
    dialog_shownote.setContentView(R.layout.wr_dialog);
    dialog_shownote.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog_shownote.setCancelable(true);
```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation to find out what package Window comes from?

Comment: "An instance of this class should be used as the top-level view added to the window manager...The only existing implementation of this abstract class is android.policy.PhoneWindow, which you should instantiate when needing a Window. ". Still don't know what to do.

Comment: I don't understand. The class's package is right there in that documentation page, near the top. What exactly is blocking you from using the appropriate `import`?

Comment: Yes as per User:Mat comment. You've to use `import android.view.Window;` this package.

Comment: Mat please add this as a solution. Idk why i had to manually import this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do it that way. You should use `Dialog` class to build your `Dialog` from scratch or, the easy way, you can do it by defining a `style`.

So, if you don't have already a xml file with *styles* in your project just create one (your `PauseDialog` is fine) and add the lollowing lines:

```
<style name="PauseDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

After this you are able to build you `Dialog` like:

```
dialog_shownote = new Dialog(WrittenTest.this, R.style.PauseDialog);
dialog_shownote.setContentView(R.layout.wr_dialog);
dialog_shownote.setCancelable(true);
```

Lt me know if it works!

Comment: Glad to help. Plase accpet the answer if it was reaaly helpful to you.